# Passing a Class type within a constructor of another class?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Do forgive me if the title is not correct, I thought this very question has to with "Polymorphism" but didn't want to complicate the title.

I am learning Java and following "Java: Learn to Program", As I am going along, I am applying the knowledge and creating my own scenarios to see
how "Polymorphism" is applied. I would appreciate it if someone can help me understand how to do this task. I have three classes:

1. Abstract Employee
2. Manager (Subclass of Employee)
3. Restaurant

Employee class and Manager class are pretty straight forward. I am trying to create a restaurant and every restaurant has a manager. My question is:

Should I pass "Manager" type as constructor arguments of "Restaurant" class or instantiate the "Manager" object in the constructor?

```
public abstract class Employee{

    private String _empName;
    private double _empSalary;

    public Employee( string name, double salary){

        _empName = name;
        _empSalary = salary;
    }

    public void setEmpName( String name ){
        _empName = name;
    }

    public String getEmpName(){
        return _empName;
    }

    public void setEmpSalary( double salary ){
        _empSalary = salary;
    }

    public double getEmpSalary(){
        return _empSalary;
    }
}//CLASS


public class Manager{

    private double _yrsOfExp;

    public Manager( String name, double salary, double experience ){
        super(name, salary);
        _yrsOfExp = experience;
    }

    public void setManagerExperience( double years ){
        _yrsOfExp = years;
    }

    public double getManagerExperience(){
        return _yrsOfExp;
    }

}//CLASS
```

This is where I need help, I am declaring the constructor with "MANAGER TYPE". Should I be declaring the instance of "Manager" with the construction instead of 
passing "Manager type" with the constructor, please?

```
public class Restaurant{

    private Manager _manager;
    private String _location;

    //CONSTRUCTOR 1
    //SHOULD I PURSUE IT THIS WAY OR
    public Restaurant( Manager manager, String location){
        _manager = manager;
        _location = location;
    }

    //CONSTRUCTOR 2
    //SHOULD I DO IT THIS WAY?  
    public Restaurant( String name, double salary, double experience, String location){
        super(name, salary, experience);
        _location = location;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String str = "";

        return str;
    }
}//CLASS
```

Answer (score 1):

This is partly a matter of taste and of what else you're going to do with the objects.

If you may ever want to refer to Managers independently, then they want to be their own object rather than properties of the Restaurant.

Since a Restaurant is not itself a Manager, I would suggest that it shouldn't take a Manager's properties in its constructor, and should instead have a Manager assigned to it (either in the constructor or in a setManager() call).

Among other things, that will make much more sense if one Manager is ever in charge of two Restaurants.

Comment: Think of it this way, do your Restaurant have manager or your Restaurant have name, salary and experience?

Comment: Thank you @keshlam. I was leaning towards my second constructor, and I gather your approach be the second constructor as well?

Comment: My recommendation based on the minimal data you've given us would be the first option. Treat the Manager as an object, rather than as properties of the Restaurant.